# Bootstrap Inline Carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to inline a Bootstrap 4 carousel with another inline-block element (represented by an `<img>` element here). But whenever I put them side-to-side, the carousel element gets shifted upwards by 50% its height. How can I have them perfectly side-by-side?

Repro JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yok78wrt/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`vertical-align:top;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)

> The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to
>   each other on a line are lined up.

The working **jsfiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/y5a0b18s/

> #### The valid values are:
>
> **baseline** - This is the default value. 
> **top** - Align the top of the
>   element and its descendants with the top of the entire line. 
> **bottom** -
>   Align the bottom of the element and its descendants with the bottom of
>   the entire line. 
> **middle** - Aligns the middle of the element with the
>   middle of lowercase letters in the parent. 
> **text-top** - Aligns the top
>   of the element with the top of the parent element's font.
>  **text-bottom** -
>   Aligns the bottom of the element with the bottom of the parent
>   element's font. 
> **sub** - Aligns the baseline of the element with the
>   subscript-baseline of its parent. Like where a  would sit. 
> **super**
>   - Aligns the baseline of the element with the superscript-baseline of its parent. Like where a  would sit. 
> **length** - Aligns the baseline
>   of the element at the given length above the baseline of its parent.
>   *(e.g. px, %, em, rem, etc.)*

Answer (score 5):

Go to inspect element and you will get that  tag has a property vertical-align: middle. That's why your image is not aligned side by side.

You can add a custom class to your css file and like that

```
<img class="image-position" src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200">
```

and in the css file you need to write:

```
.image-position {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-style: none;
}
```

after doing that the image and the slider will be side by side as you want.